# WCF basicHttpBinding streamed keep alive

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, keep-alive, basichttpbinding

I'm using a self-hosted WCF service with this `basicHttpBinding`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streamedHttp"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             messageEncoding="Mtom"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
             maxBufferSize="67108864" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

If the connection is not used in the first 10 minutes (default `receiveTimeout`) after application start, it (**EDIT**: the connection, not the host application) will be closed. To avoid this, I'm looking for a possibility to keep the connection alive. Just increasing the `receiveTimeout` does not seem to be a good approach... A `reliableSession` can't be established because of `transferMode=Streamed`.

Could I do anything else than calling an empty service method periodically?

Comment: Show me your code. Generally speaking, the service host would not be closed automatically. I don’t think the timeout property will work. For my self-host WCF service, I use the console application to host the service, in the USING statement, I use the Console.Readline() statement to prevent the service stopped automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that's not the problem. The connection closes, not the host application! Sorry, maybe my description was not clear enough...

Comment: have you tried the below timetout property? did it work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding

Comment: Like already mentioned in the question, increasing the `receiveTimeout` would delay dropping the connection. But that's not what I'm looking for!
For me, a timeout is something to handle cases where an operations takes more time than normally. So it's a error handling thing... In my case, not using the service for the first 10,100 or 1000 minutes is no error. So I don't want to do a hack using an error handling mechanism.